# ObjectDisposedException in xamarin HttpClient.PutAsync

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I faced a problem with Xamarin's `HttpClient` `PutAsync` method in a simple application. It has a `ListActivity` subclass with an `OnListItemClick` method overriden.

```
protected override async void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    var item = this.itemList[position];

    var core = new MyClass();
    await core.Toggle(item);
}
```

`MyClass` contains only one method:

```
internal async Task Toggle(string id)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new StringContent("test");

        var url = $"http://192.168.1.35/api/Toggle/{id}"

        using (var result = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content))
        {
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

I always get an `ObjectDisposedException` in `httpClient.PutAsync`. It says that `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` was disposed.

But if I change `PutAsync` to `GetAsync` everything works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick tip that I've learned while using HttpClient: you may want to save the HttpClient instance and reuse it for multiple requests. That is how it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. There was no controller registered to handle Toggle method on the web service. When this was fixed I succeeded to get 200 OK. But I still wonder why PutAsync gave me ObjectDisposedException instead of more appropriate Bad Request.